# What is Tunnel Adapter means-

Tags: networking, python

Iam writing a code to print the all devices connected in the network using python pcapy. In the out put, it prints

"Tunnel adapter isatap" details .

Can anyone please tell me what it would means... i was expected to get print the interface name which ever is named with.

Please see the attached screen shot

Appreciate for the support

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Those *are* interface names – for certain virtual interfaces.

"Tunneling", in networking, means running some protocol inside another same-layer or higher-layer protocol (e.g. IP over IP, or IP over UDP, or even IP over HTTP). For example, VPNs are tunnels.

So "Tunnel adapter" means a virtual interface which encapsulates packets inside some form of tunnel/VPN protocol, and sends those over *another* interface.

The 3 adapters you're seeing are built into Windows and used for **IPv6 transition** – that is, providing IPv6 functionality when you're on an IPv4-only network.

- "6to4" uses public anycast relay servers; the protocol is IP-in-IP, aka "6in4" or "protocol 41". The 6to4 adapter only works when your computer has a global (public) IPv4 address.
- "ISATAP" uses local (corporate) relay servers; it speaks the same protocol. The ISATAP adapter only works if it finds a relay on the local network (quite rare).
- "Teredo" uses public relay servers and speaks a UDP-based tunnel protocol. It doesn't have special requirements, but often doesn't work reliably at all.

In general, you can ignore these interfaces and even safely disable all three tunnel mechanisms (via `netsh interface ipv6 ...`).

Comment: Thanks @Grawity.. this is much helpful appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

ISATAP is an adapter in your OS that can be used to send ipv6 frames over an ipv4 network.

It can be used to help 'migrate' ipv4 networks to ipv6 until ipv6 is fully deployed.